# Sum only values if value of next day has the same value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table TAB1 and need to SUM values GROUP BY name column which is easy but I need to SUM only the values = 24 but only if the value with next date is 24 too.

St. like

```
SELECT name, SUM(value) AS SUM_VALUE 
FROM TAB1 
WHERE value = 24 AND --next value of the same name with DATEADD(day,1,date) is 24 too
GROUP BY name
```

Thanks in advance for your help, regards Petr

```
   name *date       *value  
    ***************************
    text1   *2016-06-01 *8
    text2   *2016-06-01 *4
    text1   *2016-06-02 *24
    text2   *2016-06-02 *8
    text1   *2016-06-03 *24
    text2   *2016-06-03 *24
    text1   *2016-06-04 *6
    text2   *2016-06-04 *24
    text1   *2016-06-05 *24
    text2   *2016-06-05 *24
    text1   *2016-06-06 *24
    text2   *2016-06-06 *8
    text1   *2016-06-07 *24
    text2   *2016-06-07 *24
    text1   *2016-06-08 *6
    text2   *2016-06-08 *24
    text1   *2016-06-09 *24
    text2   *2016-06-09 *24

calculation algorithm
1 - 48 => 0
2 - 72 => 24
1 - 72 => 24
2 - 72 => 24

The result should be

    name    *SUM_VALUE
    ******************
    text1   *24
    text2   *48
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? In all of them you can use a self join to match a row with those of the previous day. In 2012 and above you can use the `LAG` function and avoid the self join

Comment: 2012 version... can you shortly show the select with the join and with the LAG function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT  name,
        SUM([value]) AS SUM_VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT y1.*
    FROM YourTable y1
    INNER JOIN YourTable y2
        ON y2.name = y1.name AND 
            y2.[date] IN (DATEADD(day,1,y1.[date]),DATEADD(day,-1,y1.[date])) AND
            y2.[value] = y1.[value] and y1.[value] = 24) as p
GROUP BY name
```

With CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT  y1.name,
        SUM(y1.[value]) AS SUM_VALUE
FROM YourTable y1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE name = y1.name AND 
        [date] IN (DATEADD(day,1,y1.[date]),DATEADD(day,-1,y1.[date])) AND
        [value] = y1.[value]
    ) as p
WHERE y1.[value] = 24
GROUP BY y1.name
```

For SQL Server 2012 and up you can use LEAD and LAG:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  *, 
        CASE WHEN [value] IN (LAG([value],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY [date]), LEAD([value],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY [date])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as r
FROM YourTable
)

SELECT  name, 
        SUM([value]) as SUM_VALUE
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1 and [value] = 24
GROUP BY name
```

Output the same for all:

```
name    SUM_VALUE
text1   48
text2   72
```

It checks if a `value` of current string is similar to previous and and next value if so it puts `1` in `r` column.

**EDIT1**

Use `((SUM([value])/24)/3) * 24` instead of `SUM([value])`

**EDIT2**

I use this with data from your question:

```
;WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('text1', '2016-06-01', 8),
('text2', '2016-06-01', 4),
('text1', '2016-06-02', 24),
('text2', '2016-06-02', 8),
('text1', '2016-06-03', 24),
('text2', '2016-06-03', 24),
('text1', '2016-06-04', 6),
('text2', '2016-06-04', 24),
('text1', '2016-06-05', 24),
('text2', '2016-06-05', 24),
('text1', '2016-06-06', 24),
('text2', '2016-06-06', 8),
('text1', '2016-06-07', 24),
('text2', '2016-06-07', 24),
('text1', '2016-06-08', 6),
('text2', '2016-06-08', 24),
('text1', '2016-06-09', 24),
('text2', '2016-06-09', 24)
) as t(name, [date], [value])
), cte AS (
SELECT  *, 
        CASE WHEN [value] IN (LAG([value],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY [date]), LEAD([value],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY [date])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as r
FROM YourTable
)

SELECT  name, 
        ((SUM([value])/24)/3) * 24 as SUM_VALUE
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1 and [value] = 24
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
name    SUM_VALUE
text1   24
text2   48
```

Comment: It's nearly good but maybe I have wrong explanation... I need to get total SUM of all SUM of 24 values which are consecutive by date

Comment: Within date ranges?

Comment: why a date range? simple need to sum all values 24 if they have next value 24 too including the last in the sequence

Comment: I was a bit slow typing an edit. I meant "batchs" so test1 batch1 would start 2016-06-01 and terminate 2016-06-03 because 2016-06-04 value is 6, test1 batch2 would start 2016-06-04 but is not totalled because it drops off the end of the table before there are enough 24s or a subsequent low value is encountered.

Comment: @gofr1 : Thanks a lot, it's functional :-) ...do you know how to do it only by JOINs ?

Comment: @Petr I added this to my answer!

Comment: @gofr1 : Do you know the solution if the SUM could start as soon as the value is 48 ? It menas the first two valid values are not counted and the result should be only text2 - 24

Comment: @Petr On your place I'll just add `SUM([value]) - 48` in `SELECT ` part and add `HAVING SUM([value]) - 48 > 0`

Comment: @gofr1  I just tried it and it's not fully functional as I expected. I have edited the request pattern. Please look at it and try to solve it :-) Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Petr I will take a look

Comment: I add some info to my answer. With sample data from your question

Comment: We take `SUM([value])` then divide it by `24` to count how many times `24` contains in this sum, then divide this by `3` so for `text2` we get  `6/3=2` for `text1` we get `5/3=1` (that's how division of integers in SQL Server works) then we multiply result by `24` to get result you need.

Comment: Yes your description is perfect but it's not the algorithm which I need. In reality there can be more than 3 valid values in sequence and we need to sum it as first part of the result. Then we can have several valid parts of sum and in the end we need to sum the valid parts of the values.

Comment: So if there is 2 times 24 in a row then = 48 (`48-48=0`) if > 3 times in row then it should be for example 5 - `5*24-2*24=72` am I understanding right?

Comment: yes you are right 5*24 (72) next is 2*24 (0) next can be 3*24(24) and the total sum is of the parts 72 + 0 + 24...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know the result...

```
    select a.[name], sum(a.[value]) as sum_value
    from table a inner join  (select b.[name], b.[date] from table b where b.[value] = 24) as c 
     on a.name = c.name and where dateadd(d, 1, a.date) = c.date
    group by a.[name]
```